# Can't create a generic JNIEnv due to the error "thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value

Tags: rust, java-native-interface

I want to create a generic `JNIEnv` (alongside a `JObject`) with a `JString` of a fixed value (e.g. "fake javastring") to test a few functions that require a `JEnv` and `JObject` to work properly. I don't want to run a Java VM.

I tried creating generic `None`-value `JNIEnv` but that fails with the error:

```
failures:

---- main_tests::Jstrings::return_fake_string stdout ----
thread 'main_tests::Jstrings::return_fake_string' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error(NullPtr("from_raw ptr argument"), State { next_error: None, backtrace: InternalBacktrace })', src/libcore/result.rs:999:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
stack backtrace:
   0: std::sys::unix::backtrace::tracing::imp::unwind_backtrace
             at src/libstd/sys/unix/backtrace/tracing/gcc_s.rs:39
   1: std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:71
   2: std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:59
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:197
   3: std::panicking::default_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:208
   4: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:474
   5: std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:381
   6: rust_begin_unwind
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:308
   7: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at src/libcore/panicking.rs:85
   8: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/a53f9df32fbb0b5f4382caaad8f1a46f36ea887c/src/libcore/macros.rs:18
   9: core::result::Result<T,E>::unwrap
             at /rustc/a53f9df32fbb0b5f4382caaad8f1a46f36ea887c/src/libcore/result.rs:800
  10: rust::empty_jnienv
             at src/main.rs:10
  11: rust::main_tests::Jstrings::return_fake_string
             at src/main.rs:29
  12: rust::main_tests::Jstrings::return_fake_string::{{closure}}
             at src/main.rs:27
  13: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/a53f9df32fbb0b5f4382caaad8f1a46f36ea887c/src/libcore/ops/function.rs:231
  14: <alloc::boxed::Box<F> as core::ops::function::FnOnce<A>>::call_once
             at /rustc/a53f9df32fbb0b5f4382caaad8f1a46f36ea887c/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:704
  15: __rust_maybe_catch_panic
             at src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:85
  16: test::run_test::run_test_inner::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/a53f9df32fbb0b5f4382caaad8f1a46f36ea887c/src/libstd/panicking.rs:272
             at /rustc/a53f9df32fbb0b5f4382caaad8f1a46f36ea887c/src/libstd/panic.rs:394
             at src/libtest/lib.rs:1468
```

My code - Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "rust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2"
jni = { version = "0.10.2", default-features = false }
```

main.rs

```
mod backend;

extern crate libc;

use jni::objects::{JObject, JString};
use jni::JNIEnv;
use std::ptr;

pub unsafe fn empty_jnienv() -> jni::JNIEnv<'static> {
    jni::JNIEnv::from_raw(ptr::null_mut()).unwrap()
}

pub unsafe fn empty_jobj() -> jni::objects::JObject<'static> {
    jni::objects::JObject::null()
}

fn main() {}

#[cfg(test)]
mod main_tests {
    use super::*;

    mod Jstrings {
        use super::*;

        #[test]
        fn return_fake_string() {
            let this_string = "fake javastring";
            let jenv = unsafe { empty_jnienv() };
            let jobj = unsafe { empty_jobj() };
            let jstr: jni::objects::JString = jenv.new_string(this_string.to_owned()).unwrap();
            assert!(unsafe {
                backend::Java_com_example_android_MainActivity_test(jenv, jobj, jstr) == true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

backend.rs

```
use jni::objects::{JObject, JString};
use jni::JNIEnv;
use std::ffi::{CStr, CString};

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn Java_com_example_android_MainActivity_test(
    env: JNIEnv,
    _: JObject,
    j_recipient: JString,
) -> bool {
    let mut this_return = false;
    let recipient = CString::from(CStr::from_ptr(
        env.get_string(j_recipient).unwrap().as_ptr(),
    ));

    if recipient.to_str().unwrap() == "fake javastring" {
        this_return = true;
    }
    this_return
}
```

Is there a way to solve this without running a Java VM to create the `JNIEnv` and `JObject`?

Comment: If you want to test your logic, make the JNI wrappers as thin as possible, so that they don't contain any logic. Just unwrapping and wrapping code, with the actual logic in a function that doesn't need any of that JNI stuff. Then test *that*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside `jni.h`, you will see that a `JNIEnv*` is a big struct filled with function pointers:

```cpp
struct JNINativeInterface_ {
    void *reserved0;
    void *reserved1;
    void *reserved2;

    void *reserved3;
    jint (JNICALL *GetVersion)(JNIEnv *env);

    jclass (JNICALL *DefineClass)
      (JNIEnv *env, const char *name, jobject loader, const jbyte *buf,
       jsize len);
    jclass (JNICALL *FindClass)
      (JNIEnv *env, const char *name);

    // and so on
};

typedef const struct JNINativeInterface_ *JNIEnv;
```

If you really want to pursue this path, you could implement just the functions your code needs and assign them to the various members of `JNINativeInterface_`.
I don't know much about the Rust bridge you are using, but converting such a `JNIEnv` pointer should work.

Of course the final question is: what *are* you actually testing then?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation of [`JNIEnv::from_raw()`](https://docs.rs/jni/0.10.1/jni/struct.JNIEnv.html#method.from_raw) says, it does not do too much, but

> Create a JNIEnv from a raw pointer.
>
> Only does a null check - otherwise assumes that the pointer is valid.

So passing that `ptr::null_mut()` already triggers this, and then comes the first line of your error message telling the same:

> ```
> called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error(NullPtr("from_raw ptr argument") [...]
> ```

Literally saying that the null pointer resulted in an error, instead of `JNIEnv`, and thus it can not `unwrap()`.

TL;DR: no, what you do will not work, Java does not work without Java, and based on some later parts of the code probably it is worth adding that Android will not work without Android either. Even if you properly configure and use Java, having it run an `Activity` will be a whole new challenge.